# Increment id from URL with retrofit Android Studios Kotlin

Tags: http, kotlin, retrofit

I need your help since I'm struggling, I want to make some HTTP GET requests which allow me to retrieve each JSON object one by one in order to store them in a List which I will then put in an adapter. I intend to do it by incrementing `idPlayer` at each loop in the URL but given how the retrofit library was designed I wonder if this is possible.
Thx :)

```
    fun getplayer() {
        var instancePlayer = InstancePlayer()
        var playerApi = instancePlayer.getPlayerAPI()

            var call = playerApi?.getPlayer("/api/v1/players/" + idPlayer)
            if (call != null) {
                call.enqueue(object : Callback<Player?> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Player?>, response: Response<Player?>) {
                        var responseBody = response.body()!!
                        var p1: Player = Player()
                        p1.id = responseBody.id
                        p1.first_name = responseBody.first_name
                        p1.last_name = responseBody.last_name
                        playerAdapter.setData(playerList)
                        recyclerView?.setAdapter(playerAdapter)
                        playerList.add(p1)

                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Player?>, t: Throwable) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                })

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is besides the point (in a way), but the REST API should really have an endpoint to give you the list directly. It feels quite wrong to issue N requests this way, let alone guessing IDs by increment.

Comment: Now back to the question. If you *really* want to do this, what exactly is the problem here? What in " the design of Retrofit" prevents you from just running this method in a loop where you pass the player ID to it?